# javascript: assigning functions as callbacks and variable scope

Tags: javascript

So, here's the deal. I'm using an onclick event to fire a function so with each click you will toggle between the divs original innerHTML and another variable. It works when I assign testfunction as a callback. Here's the code:

```
var c = '';

function testfunction()
{
    var a = this.innerHTML;

    var b = 'blah';

    if (a !== b)
    {
        c = a;
        return this.innerHTML = b;
    }
    else
    {
        return this.innerHTML = c;
    }

    window.onload = function()
    {
         document.getElementById('rightcontent').onclick = testfunction;
    }
```

I understand that the c retains it's value because of it's global scope. But what I don't understand is why c comes back undefined when I put the function into an anonymous callback as such:

```
    windows.onload = function()
    {
    document.getElementById('rightcontent').onclick = function()
    {
         this.innerHTML = testfunction();
    }
    }
```

There isn't a point to any of this, I'm just messing around...but I would like to know what's happening under the hood.

Sorry if this is covered elsewhere, I have looking through some posts to find my answer, but I can't find it.

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Search for `[javascript] this scope` or similar.

Comment: Did you mean to set `window.onload` inside `testfunction`?

Comment: @JustinMorgan : No, but I don't know why I should or shouldn't. Also, I corrected testfunction(), now the returns correct.

Comment: [`window.onload` runs when the document is finished loading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onload). So if you're calling `testfunction` any time after that event, setting `window.onload` won't do anything. I don't know what you're trying to do, and it's possible to run code before the DOM loads, but it's not the most common thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I understand that the c retains it's value because of it's global scope. But what I don't understand is why c comes back undefined when I put the function into an anonymous callback as such:

In your second snippet, `this` is not equal to `#rightcontent`, it's equal to `window`. `window.innerHTML` is undefined so the first branch is taken in your `if/else` block.

`c` gets assigned `undefined`, and `undefined` is returned.

You can call a method and specify a particular context with [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply):

```
document.getElementById('rightcontent').onclick = function () {
    this.innerHTML = testfunction.call(this);
}
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/dySA5/

The reason your first snippet doesn't exhibit this behavior is because the browser is setting `this` to be the clicked element when the method is called.

Comment: Thanks a ton! I corrected testfunction() returns though.  Few things : Does the 'this' in the return portion of the testfunction() also refer the window? or has it moved to the div once called? AND it's interesting, when using the anonymous callback way, you can just return the var, rather than this.innerHTML = var. Why is that? Also,for the anonymous callback, you can use either return this.innerHTML = var or just return = var, and it gives the same results... it this supposed to be that way?

Comment: Also, when assigning testfunction() to onclick, I have to use the return this.innerHTML = var.

Comment: @whosmav: *when using the anonymous callback way, you can just return the var, rather than this.innerHTML = var. Why is that?*: Because you are assigning the return value inside the anonymous callback: `this.innerHTML = testfunction.call(this);`. There is nothing magical about it, you just assign the value at a different line. Also, FYI: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/2aDJS/4/

I cleaned up and jQuerified your example to make it a little easier to read:

```
var c = '';

function testfunction() {
  console.log(this)
  var a = this.innerHTML;

  var b = 'blah';

  if (a !== b) {
    c = a;
    this.innerHTML = b;
  } else {
    this.innerHTML = c;
  }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#rightcontent').click(function () {
    testfunction.call(this);
    //testfunction();
  });

  //$('#rightcontent').click(testfunction);
})
```

The reason you're seeing the function call within that is wrapped in a function fail is because the scope changes when you do that. `this` is interpreted as the event inducing element on the event handler. If you call a function inside your event handler and want it to refer it's `this` will be unaltered unless you specifically invoke the scope using `function.call(scope)`.